# При сравнении выводит только одно значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

При вводе любого значения выполняется 3 условие

```py
def takeVar():
    print ('Write a number')
    spam = input()
    return spam
def conditionChecker ():
    if takeVar == str(1):
        print ('Nice')
    elif takeVar == str(2):
        print ('Howdy')
    else:
        print ('Good job')
    return 0

takeVar()
conditionChecker()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции в Python являются объектами. Когда Вы пишете `takeVar == str(1)`, то Вы, на самом деле, не сравниваете результат выполнения `takeVar` со строковым представлением единицы. Вы сравниваете функцию со строкой - а это сродни сравнению тёплого с мягким. Вам нужно вызвать функцию, чтобы получить результат.

Функция вызывается, если вслед за неё следуют скобки: `takeVar()`. Сравнение `takeVar(1) == str(1)` уже будет осмысленным. Однако в Вашем случае появляется ещё одна проблема. Если первое условие не будет выполнено, то вы снова хотите вызвать `takeVar()`. Но это значит, что от пользователя снова потребуют ввод вместо того, чтобы проверять первоначальное число!

Вам стоит вызвать функцию `takeVar` лишь один раз, и запомнить результат. Затем использовать его при сравнениях. Выглядеть это будет так:

```
def take_var():
    print('Write a number')
    spam = input()
    return spam

def condition_checker():
    var = take_var()
    if var == str(1):
        print ('Nice')
    elif var == str(2):
        print ('Howdy')
    else:
        print ('Good job')
    return 0

condition_checker()
```

Вызывать `take_var()` после определения функций также не нужно, ведь она вызывается внутри `condition_checker`.

Заметьте, что я немного изменил стиль кода. При работе с кодом на Python старайтесь использовать рекомендации [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).